# Selenium_chrome not visible; always headless

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

Capybara is working fine except I can't see it.

Both these configurations run "headless" and I can't see the browser.

Expect to see Chrome running:
`Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome`

Expect headless behavior:
`Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless`

I'm trying to debug and I'd like to pause execution (pry) and work with Chrome in its current state. How do I make Chrome NOT headless?

**Edit:**

We're using RSpec.

This is the the only occurrence of `current_driver` in the codebase:

```
# spec/support/capybara_support.rb
def resize_window(width, height)
  case Capybara.current_driver
  when :selenium, :chrome, :selenium_chrome, :selenium_chrome_headless, :webkit
    Capybara.current_session.current_window.resize_to(width, height)
  else
    raise NotImplementedError,
          "resize_window is not supported by #{Capybara.current_driver}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using RSpec or Minitest? Are you using Rails system tests? Do you have any code setting Capybara.current_driver?

Comment: Also happening if you set `Capybara.default_driver = selenium_chrome` ?

Comment: @Meltemi Show one of your tests, I'm guessing you're either writing system tests and not using `driven_by` , or writing feature tests but not specifying the `js` metadata to trigger changing to the driver set by `javascript_driver`.  Showing an actual test definition would help to confirm that.